# Mysql PDO (Getting total from all colums)

Tags: mysql, pdo

So, I'm using select sum(MyColumn) as MyColumnSum from MyTable as my query to get the total amount of payments I received.

How would I run this in MYSQL PDO? I'm used to Mysqli.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: I've researched into the MySQL command that I should run :P. I no nothing of MySQL PDO.

Comment: You should show us your code and table structure.